# Projectile limit in Processing?

Tags: processing

I have a simple proof-of-concept sketch for a recreation of the Wii Play "Tanks" game, implementing a movable player and clicking to fire. I wrote a `Bullet` class which provides `void show()`, `void tick(Wall[] walls)`, and `boolean offScreen()` methods. I want the Player class to be limited to 5 bullets in the air at once. My solution is a wrapper class for a given number of bullets. It draws each, ticks each, etc., but as soon as a bullet is offscreen (or close enough) it removes it. "walls" is the list of walls, which the bullet class detects & teleports offscreen. Here's the code for that bit:

```
    Bullet[] goodBullets = new Bullet[limit];
    int goodCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      if (bullets[i] == null) {
        continue;
      } else if (bullets[i].offScreen()) {
        continue;
      } else {
        goodBullets[goodCount] = bullets[i];
        goodBullets[goodCount].tick(walls);
        goodCount++;
      }
    }
    bullets = goodBullets;
```

I can't help but feel this is a terrible way to handle this. Is there some obvious thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough code to really assess if this is a good pattern or how to improve on it, but at a glimpse this makes sense.

In the Bullet class, make sure that you don't draw, update or check collisions with offscreen bullets. Instead of a "offscreen" property, I often use a "isVisible" boolean (or anything which would be meaningful to you) that I'll turn off as soon as the object stops "existing", si I also stop manipulating it.

After all, it's a waste of good cpu to make that bullet go to infinity and beyond, isn't it?

You are right about the being able to improve on the `if` I see here.

It's good practice to make calculate conditions in a way which is affirmative. So, Instead of doing:

```
Check if:
1. bullet is null (then do nothing)
2. bullet is offscreen (then do nothing)
3. then do something
```

You should just check for the third case instead:

```
Check if:
1. bullet isn't null or offscreen
```

Like this:

```
if (bullet[i] != null && !bullet[i].offScreen()) {
  goodBullets[goodCount] = bullets[i];
  goodBullets[goodCount].tick(walls);
  goodCount++;
}
```

The rest of the logic isn't easy to grasp and reflect on from this snippet only, though, but I get that it's not that easy to boil down a program idea to a paragraph of code - and, anyway, SO's crowd like specific questions, so "improve on my 3 pages of code" is normally the kind of question which quickly gets removed.

As a last though: to accomplish this "only 5 bullets" goal but with some efficiency, I would approach the situation using [the "object pool" design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/object_pool). In short, you can make a class which will "lend" you the bullets and get them back when they are not in use.

Have fun!

Comment: Please note that I changed the `||` operator for an `&&` after you review this answer (the boolean math didn't make sense with the OR).